# Invoking Java keyword super

Tags: java, super

I had the following code on a test for a potential job recently.

```
class Point {
    protected final int x, y;
    private final String name;

    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        name = makeName();
    }

    protected String makeName() {
        return "[" + x + "," + y + "]";
    }

    public final String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class ColorPoint extends Point {
    private final String color;

    ColorPoint(int x, int y, String color) {
        super(x, y);
        this.color = color;
    }

    protected String makeName() {
        return super.makeName() + ": " + color;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new ColorPoint(4, 2, "purple"));
    }
}
```

The test asked what the programmer intended to have printed out, which was [4, 2]: purple.  It also asked what actually prints out, which is [4: 2]: null.  What I'd like to find out is why.

Comment: Constructors should not call methods that can be overridden. They may run on "half-initialized" instances, as in this case.

Comment: Btw, this question is straight out of Java Puzzlers by Joshua Bloch (as in, they're identical to the character). It's puzzle 51. It's a good book to read if you want to find other interesting edge cases in the Java language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the subclass `ColorPoint` when the constructor of the super class `Point` is called, the value to the variable `color` is yet to be assigned. Hence when `makeName()` method is called, `color` is actually `null`, hence the `name` variable becomes `[4,2]:null`, and thats what you see when you print.

Answer (score 3):

Observe what happens when you create a new `ColorPoint` instance:

- memory is allocated for a `ColorPoint` instance
- `x`, `y` and `name` are set to their default values
- the `ColorPoint` constructor is called
- the `ColorPoint` constructor calls the `Point` constructor
- the `Point` constructor assigns to `x` and `y`
- the `Point` constructor calls the `makeName` method.
- `this.makeName` resolves to `ColorPoint.makeName`
- `ColorPoint.makeName` calls `Point.makeName`
- `Point.makeName` observes `x` and `y` already set, and acts as desired
- `ColorPoint.makeName` observes `color` to be `null`, and acts accordingly
- the `Point` constructor assigns to `name` and returns
- the `ColorPoint` constructor assigns to `color` and returns. Oops, too late.

The `final` keyword ensures a particular field or variable will be assigned to exactly once (the compiler does that; it's still possible to change via reflection). The compiler also ensures a local variable will not be read before it's been written to. There is no such provision of write before read for class fields.

That's why, as has been noted, you should never call methods that can be overriden from the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is obvious in the code.

The `ColorPoint` `makeName` method is called from the constructor of `Point` class. At that point the `private final variable color` has not been initialized.

Comment: and there is no easy way to fix this. You cannot move the assignment before the call to the super-constructor, because that has to be the first thing to happen.

Comment: The easy way to fix it is to remember that premature optimization is the root of all evils, and to just generate the string in `toString()`.

Comment: The question was a job interview test. It is bound to have convoluted design to see if someone can make sense of it.